# jQuery tablesorter - two sorting options per column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Question is related to this example here: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html

I want to make two sorting options on one column.
Let’s say that I want to make radio buttons above the table.
One button would be to sort grades by name and another to sort grades by grades.

How could I do that? I’ve tried various solutions, but none work the way I want.

This is my last code but works only for the first chosen sort type. To sort by another type I have to refresh.

```
function btnPressed(){
  if (document.getElementById("byName").checked === true){
    $(function() {
      $("table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
      });
    });
  } else if (document.getElementById("byGrade").checked === true){
    // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
      // set a unique id
      id: 'grades',
      is: function(s, table, cell, $cell) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
      },
      format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        // format your data for normalization
        return s.toLowerCase()
          .replace(/good/,2)
          .replace(/medium/,1)
          .replace(/bad/,0);
      },
      // set type, either numeric or text
      type: 'numeric'
    });

    $(function() {
      $("table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
        // "sorter-grades" added as a class name in the HTML (new in v2.0.11)
        // or un-comment out the option below
        // ,headers: { 6: { sorter: 'grades' } }
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Look under "Sort column content" here - https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#sorting - some demos may not work until you switch from jQuery (edge) to jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: Excellent. This is even better because it means that I don't have to use radio buttons at all. Solved with method 2. Thanks